# Thoughts on ways to re order network routes file with bash / sed / awk script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Re framing to try and clarify the issue ...

I have multiple network route files which have configurations issues. In the static routes file, routes are grouped in blocks of 3 and identified by the numbered appended to the ADDRRES/NETMASK/GATEWAY before the =:

```
ADDRESS0=X.X.X.X
NETMASK0=X.X.X.X
GATEWAY0=X.X.X.X

ADDRESS0=X.X.X.X is the network number for the static route.
NETMASK0=X.X.X.X is the netmask for the network number defined with ADDRESS0=X.X.X.X
GATEWAY0=X.X.X.X is the default gateway, or an IP address that can be used to reach ADDRESS0=X.X.X.X
```

Linux will then add the route, based on the number assigned to each group.

Subsequent static routes (The ADDRESS# , NETMASK# , GATEWAY# portion) must be numbered sequentially, and must not skip any values. For example, ADDRESS0,NETMASK0,GATEWAY0 , THEN, ADDRESS1,NETMASK1,GATEWAY1 and so on.

For example a good configuration would like but the hosts could have >20 entries :

```
ADDRESS0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS3=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK3=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY3=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My issue to two fold...

ONE : Duplicate static routes. In this configuration it will iterate through the file adding the routes for each numbered
group 0 - 2. However because there is two ADDRESS1/NETMASK1/GATEWAY1 entries one of them will not be added...

```
GATEWAY2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

TWO: They are not in sequential order. In this example it will iterate from the numbered groups of routes 0-2, but it will stop there because ADDRESS3/NETMASK3/GATEWAY3 does not exist. Therefore it thinks routes  ADDRESS4 and ADDRESS5 do not exist and therefore aren't added.

```
ADDRESS0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS5=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK5=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY5=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I would like to remove / change the numbers appended to ADDRESS/NETMASK/GATEWAY and increment them, but not change the values
assigned to them designated by the "=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

So for instance in Example two it would become. Therefore I'm looking for a way to iterate through a file, change the number appended to ADDRESS/NETMASK/GATEWAY and increment that number :

```
ADDRESS0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY2=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS3=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK3=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY3=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ADDRESS4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY4=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I was thinking for iterating through the file for every instance ^ADDRESS and changing/incrementing that number from 0. And repeating with ^NETMASK and ^GATEWAY. But I've failed to find a way to implement it. If you need further clarification, please let me know. Many thanks in advance

Comment: so they key is the unique data that you show as `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` ? You want to make a list of unique `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`'s then generate `ADDRESSn`,`NETMASKn`,`GATEWAYn` "records" for eack in the list?

Comment: No, a combination of sed+awk is **never** the right answer for any problem since awk can do anything sed can do so if you're already using awk then you don't need to add sed. Your question is extremely unclear though. Don't assue we have any knowledge of your domain - it's all just rows and columns to us so [edit] your question and try again to describe your problem with that in mind and clarify if your posted "Desired end state" (expected output?) is from the first or 2nd sample input file you provided. If from the 2nd, where did the ADDRESS3, etc. info come from?

Comment: Thanks guys, tried to clarify a bit better ...

Answer (score 0):

The following script does roughly what you want.

- collect 3-tuples by the appended id in the input
- renumber them consecutively
- check for duplicate ids
- check for "short tuples", where one of the three is missing

(I added the last requirement.) :-)

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "=" }

/^ADDRESS|^NETMASK|^GATEWAY/ {
    id = substr($1, 8)
    sub(id "=", "%d=", $0)
    if( id in matched && 3 == split(matched[id], foo, "\n") ) {
        printf("error: %d already encountered", id) > "/dev/stderr"
        next
    }
    matched[id] = matched[id] $0 "\n"
}

END {
    for( id in matched ) {
        if( 3 != split(matched[id], foo, "\n") ) {
            printf("error: short set for %d: %s\n", id, matched[id]) > "/dev/stderr"
            next
        }
        printf(matched[id], i, i, i) 
        i++
    }
}
```

Note the output will be ordered consecutively, but the rules will be in a different order.   To keep them in order, I'd probably collect and emit one tuple at a time.